# defining a new infix command

Tags: macros

This question kind of already exists here: [How to write infix macro/newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38694/how-to-write-infix-macro-newcommand)

But I'm not looking for a way to divide using an infix command, which I know there already exists a command for.  I'm looking for a way to define a new binary infix command for *any* purpose. Something like

```
\infixnewcommand{\T}{{bunchofstuff} {#1} {bunchofstuff} {#2} {bunchofstuff}}
```

Then later on in the code, `{2 z \T 3 y}` would get replaced with `{{bunchofstuff} {2 z} {bunchofstuff} {3 y} {bunchofstuff}}`.

Also, the wobsite wouldn't let me comment on the other question, saying I didn't have the rep, so I was kind of forced to start a new question, at least until I have enough rep to comment. Sorry about that :D

The particular example I'm faced with is defining tfrac, but as infix, so I guess it would be tover. But just to be clear, I'm not interested in a "solution" involving a pre-existing package where tover is defined. tover is just the current example at hand. I'm interested in knowing how *I* could define such a command in my own code, since I can easily see my future self requiring this capability.

Comment: It is not possible to read the tokens before your macros.  There are only a couple of exceptions, e.g. plain TeX's `\over` and `\choose`.

Comment: If you allow `\infixnotation{<stuff> \T <more stuff>}`, then yes...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. The answer to your question is really: No, you can't define an infix macro, only the primitive ones are available. But I'll let some more educated people write a proper answer.

Comment: @HenriMenke: Wow. I'm very surprised they hardcoded just those two operators without allowing such behaviour to be extended to other new operators. Oh, well. If such is the will of the Lead Developers, so be it. Thanks for the surprisingly quick answer.

Comment: @enigmaticPhysicist Note also that the primitive `\over` doesn't work like a macro; actually, when TeX sees `\over` it stores the math list it was forming, starts a new one and finally builds the fraction. The already stored math list is not reprocessed in any way, apart from fixing a style for each of its atoms.

Comment: the few primitives like `\over` that do work this way are strongly deprecated in LaTeX and defined to give a warning if you use the standard `amsmath` package.

Comment: Oh. In that case, the Wikibooks article on Latex math shouldn't mention `\over` or `\choose` at all. I think I'd better make some editions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeX works on tokens strictly in the order they enter its scanner. When a token *T* to be examined is expandable, TeX expands it looking for its arguments (without expansion). If the token *T* is a macro, it and its arguments are replaced with the replacement text; otherwise it simply disappears after having performed its action (this is the case of `\expandafter`, `\noexpand` and all conditionals, including `\else` and `\fi`).

If *T* is unexpandable, it's sent down the gullet to be executed. In some specific cases this can resurrect tokens on the main token list (it's the case of `\lowercase` and `\uppercase`).

Thus there's no way for defining an “infix macro” that can examine what comes before it, because what comes before it has already been either expanded or executed; in either case the token has disappeared and is not available any more.

The case of `\over` and related primitives (`\overwithdelims`, `\atop` and `\atopwithdelims`) is very different. They are not macros and are unexpandable, so, as said before, they are *executed*. The execution of `\over` and the others consists in putting aside the current math list that's being built, start a new one and, when finished, put it in another special place; the two saved lists are then used to form a “fraction atom” as the numerator and denominator. Delimiters are added for the `withdelims` cases and a fraction line is set for the `over` cases.

As you see, no macro expansion is involved here (of course it is when forming the two math lists, but this is irrelevant). The process takes advantage on the fact that TeX knows what math list it's working on when in math mode; however, this is not available to the user (it might be with LuaTeX, but it's a different matter).

You could fake infix notation by using special delimiters instead of `{` and `}`, but at this point a two argument macro seems more practical in a similar way as `\frac` works.

Comment: Do you know if any of this changes with LuaTeX? I.e. is it possible to define infix commands there?

Comment: @Michael I don't know and I doubt it's even possible.

Comment: For the case that it's allowed to wrap the whole thing with some macro, `regex_replace_all` can be used -- see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553842/ab-macroab

Answer (score 2):

**Important**: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/638830/250119 (and egreg's comment below) for explanation what the code does (basically do a *regex search-and-replace* on the TeX code), what are its limitations to decide whether you want to use it.

---

Source code:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rewriterest}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\Tprefix[2]{{bunchofstuff} #1 {bunchofstuff} #2 {bunchofstuff}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\rewriterest:n {
    \regex_replace_all:nnN {
        \{
            (    [^\{\}]*    )  % group 1: content does not contain any { or }
            \\T\b
            (    [^\{\}]*    )  % group 1: content does not contain any { or }
        \}
    } {
        \\Tprefix   % we're doing textual substitution here, so no \c{Tprefix}
            \{ \1 \}
            \{ \2 \}
    } \RWRbody
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

test: {2 x \T 3 y}

\end{document}
```

Output: as you can expect.

You need a package, currently its source code is at https://github.com/user202729/TeXlib