# Syntax of LaTeX macros

Tags: macros, syntax, primitives

The TeX primitive `\over` has syntax `{… \over …}`.

Is it possible to define a macro `\foo`, say, with syntax `{…}\foo{…}` *without* enclosing brackets?

Comment: no (this is a duplicate if I can find it...)

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239895/defining-a-new-infix-command