# a^b ---> \macro{a}{b}

Tags: macros

In the following code I would like to "hack" `a^b` suchas to apply `\macro{a}{b}` instead. The solution should work with natural exponent and letters eventually indexed like in `{abcd}^4` or `{x_1}^2` for example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop}

\newcounter{power}

\newcommand\macro[2]{%
    \forloop[1]{power}{0}{\value{power} < #2}{#1\kern0.3ex}%
    \kern-0.3ex%
}

\newcommand\test[1]{
    % Lost in translation...
}

\begin{document}

\test{x}         % ---> x

\test{x y}       % ---> x y

\test{x y^2}     % ---> x y y

\test{x^3 y^2 z} % ---> x x x y y z

\end{document}
```

Comment: if you just want to support official latex syntax so `x^{3+4}` or even `x^3` then it's fairly easy  to get `b` at least, just make `^` math active as done by tex4ht for example. If you want to support the primitive tex parsing and things like `x^\frac12` or `x^\mathrm{abc}`  then it's _much_ harder. getting the base is hard, and what do you want from `(x+y)^2`  is `\macro{)}{2}` acceptable?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: Classic [XY problem](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean).  You should tell us what you *actually* want to do.

Comment: This is to make a macro writing partial derivations like $f_{xxy}$ which is sometimes used by physicians.

Comment: Physicians or physicists? :-)

Comment: The froggy french is lost in translation... Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: Link to related questions-- [if it's specifically for fraction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38694/250119) // [if it must not be wrapped in an outer layer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/239895/250119).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code should be self-explaining:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m}
 {
  \projetmbc_test:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__projetmbc_test_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \projetmbc_test:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__projetmbc_test_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { (\cB. .*? \cE.|[[:alpha:]])\^ } % search a braced group or single letter followed by ^
   { \c{projetmbc_power:nn} \1 } % prepend \projetmbc_power:nn and remove ^
   \l__projetmbc_test_tl
  \ensuremath { \tl_use:N \l__projetmbc_test_tl }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \projetmbc_power:nn
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { #2 } { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\test{x}         % ---> x

\test{x y}       % ---> x y

\test{x y^2}     % ---> x y y

\test{x^3 y^2 z} % ---> x x x y y z

\test{{x_1}^3 {abcde}^2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Regex and their groups... Not so natural for me to use it with LaTeX but I will have to improve on this subject.

Comment: Note that this does not work in cases such as `{x^2}^3` because `\projetmbc_test:n` is not recursively applied to `\1`.

Comment: @user202729 Does `{x^2}^3` make sense?

Comment: Perhaps it can expand to `x^6`; but other users may want to adapt the code to some other cases which need recursive expansion. Also the user may want `{x^2 y}^3` which expands to `x x y x x y x x y`

Comment: Also note that in this case the alpha regex will make `+^6` not work (but `{+}^6` still works

Answer (score 9):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\ensuremath' macro
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' env. and '\luastringN' macro
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function test ( s )
   s = s:gsub ( "(\\%a+) ^(%d+)", string.rep ) -- e.g., '\alpha^3'
   s = s:gsub ( "(%a)^(%d+)"    , string.rep ) -- e.g., 'x^2'
   s = s:gsub ( "(%b{})^(%d+)"  , string.rep ) -- e.g., '{x_1}^4'
   tex.sprint ( s ) 
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
% Define a LaTeX wrapper macro:
\newcommand\test[1]{\directlua{test(\luastringN{#1})}} 

\begin{document}
\obeylines
\test{$x$}
\test{$x y$}
\test{$x^1 y^12$}
\test{$x^3 y^2 z$}
\test{${x_1}^3 {abcde}^2$} % courtesy of @egreg's posting
\test{$\alpha^2\lambda^3\omega^4$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: More natural for me but unfortunatly I can't use in my project.

Comment: The two last comments are good ones.    Regex fixes easily the forgot tente escaping cases.

Comment: Can Lua work with token instead of text ?

Comment: @projetmbc - Please clarify your use case.

Comment: Can Lua ignore unescaped good balanced curly braces for example ?

Comment: @projetmbc - Short answer: yes. (The code in my answer, which employs the pattern matching criterion `%b{}`, obviously does *not* ignore matching curly braces.) Please give an example of a use case that calls for ignoring matched curly braces.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question is just a general one. I will play soon with luatex.

Comment: To be more specific  I will like to split a text regarding & and \\ as in a table environment but I want to ignore this characters if they are used inside curly braces as element of a macro's argument for example.

Comment: Sure, there's `scan_toks()` function (already explained in the answer below), but if you just want to parse balanced just do a ++ when see a character { and -- when you see a character }.

Comment: @user202729 - I'm not sure I understood what you're referring to. Please clarify.

Comment: @Mico That was just (another, compared to the LuaTeX token-parsing method) reply to projetmbc's comment on how to parse balanced group, and also in case someone come across the question... not targeted to you.

Comment: @user202729 - Oh, ok.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it fully-expandably in `expl3` by absorbing tokens one-by-one.  This ignores spaces, but since you are planning to use this for partial derivatives in math mode, that shouldn't be a problem.  It might be quite slow, though.  It also doesn't work recursively, i.e. `\test{{x^3}}` will not be repeated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \mbc_process_powers:w #1 #2 #3 {
  \str_if_eq:nnF { #1 } { \q_stop }
    {
      \str_if_eq:nnTF { #2 } { ^ }
        {
          \prg_replicate:nn { #3 } { #1 }
          \mbc_process_powers:w
        } {
          #1 \mbc_process_powers:w { #2 } { #3 }
        }
    }
}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \test { m }
  {
    \mbc_process_powers:w #1 \q_stop \q_stop \q_stop
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ttfamily % nicer font for \meaning

\edef\x{\test{x}} \meaning\x         % ---> x

\edef\x{\test{x y}} \meaning\x       % ---> xy

\edef\x{\test{x y^2}} \meaning\x     % ---> xyy

\edef\x{\test{x^3 y^2 z}} \meaning\x % ---> xxxyyz

\edef\x{\test{{abcd}^4 or {x_1}^3}} \meaning\x % ---> abcdabcdabcdabcdorx_1x_1x_1

\end{document}
```

If you can't or don't want to use `expl3`, you can also implement it in normal LaTeX, but you'll need a few helper macros:

```
\makeatletter

\protected\def\@qstop{\@qstop}

\ifdefined\directlua
% LuaTeX doesn't have \pdfstrcmp.
\directlua{
function pdfstrcmp(a, b)
    if a < b then
        tex.sprint("-1")
    elseif a > b then
        tex.sprint("1")
    else
        tex.sprint("0")
    end
end
}
\long\def\pdfstrcmp#1#2{\directlua{pdfstrcmp("\luaescapestring{#1}", "\luaescapestring{#2}")}}
\fi

\def\@ifstrequal#1#2{%
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\unexpanded{#1}}{\unexpanded{#2}}=0
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
}

\def\replicate#1#2{%
    \ifnum\numexpr#1\relax>0
        #2%
        \expandafter\replicate\expandafter{\number\numexpr(#1)-1\relax}{#2}%
    \fi
}

\def\processpowers#1#2#3{%
    \@ifstrequal{#1}{\@qstop}{}{%
        \@ifstrequal{#2}{^}{%
            \replicate{#3}{#1}%
            \processpowers
        }{%
            #1\processpowers{#2}{#3}%
        }%
    }%
}

\newcommand\test[1]{\processpowers#1\@qstop\@qstop\@qstop}

\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks for this proposition. I will try it as soon as possible.

Comment: @projetmbc Regarding your question on the other answer.  Yes, LuaTeX can work with TeX tokens instead of text, but that is quite tricky.  If you are really interested, I can try to craft an answer.

Comment: That is a useful thing so if you have the time to make a example it would be great.

Answer (score 3):

In the comments you asked whether LuaTeX can also work with TeX tokens.  Instead of asking for you to explain the use-case, I will consider this as academic interest and provide an example showcasing how to do this in principle.

LuaTeX comes with the built-in `token` library which provides facilities to work with an manipulate TeX tokens.  In particular it has the function `scan_toks()` which allows to scan a list tokens delimited by balanced braces.

```
\directlua{t = token.scan_toks()}{...}
```

After this call the variable `t` will contain whatever is in `...`.  Tokens are represented as Lua tables and you can query the token's properties as elements of said table.  The elements that I use here are

- `cmdname` The name of the internal TeX command that the token represents
- `tok` The unique token identifier that TeX assigns

To compare whether two tokens are the same you can compare their `tok` properties (although care must be taken when comparing control sequences this way, since they can have additional properties such as `\protected`, `\long` or `\outer`).

Finally we can put tokens back into the input stream using `token.put_next` (which also accepts a table in which case it simple traverses the table and puts each token into the input stream).

In the example I do not wrap `\directlua` but I define a `luacall` by putting the Lua function definition into the global function table retrieved using `lua.get_functions_table()` and subsequently registering the `luacall` in TeX using `token.set_lua`.  This has some benefits which are not really relevant here but nice to have, e.g. the `\test` macro defined this way expands in a single step.

One big annoyance with this solution is that LuaTeX tokens do not “know” what input they originate from, i.e. to check whether a token contains a number we have to compare it with all tokens that result in a number as well.  For this I defined a lookup table which maps the `tok` property of the tokens to the corresponding numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
-- Lookup table to convert tokens to numbers
local numbers = {
    [token.create(string.byte("1")).tok] = 1,
    [token.create(string.byte("2")).tok] = 2,
    [token.create(string.byte("3")).tok] = 3,
    [token.create(string.byte("4")).tok] = 4,
    [token.create(string.byte("5")).tok] = 5,
    [token.create(string.byte("6")).tok] = 6,
    [token.create(string.byte("7")).tok] = 7,
    [token.create(string.byte("8")).tok] = 8,
    [token.create(string.byte("9")).tok] = 9,
    [token.create(string.byte("0")).tok] = 0,
}

-- Register a new Lua function with TeX
local lft = lua.get_functions_table()
lft[#lft + 1] = function()
    -- Scan a list of tokens delimited by balanced braces
    local toks = token.scan_toks()

    local result = {}
    local stack = {}
    local currentgrouplevel = 0
    local n = 1
    while n <= #toks do
        -- We have to scan balanced braces, so we in/decrease the
        -- currentgrouplevel on every brace
        if toks[n].cmdname == "left_brace" then
            currentgrouplevel = currentgrouplevel + 1
        elseif toks[n].cmdname == "right_brace" then
            currentgrouplevel = currentgrouplevel - 1
        end

        -- Collect tokens on a stack
        table.insert(stack, toks[n])

        -- If we are not inside braces, check for the ^
        if currentgrouplevel == 0 then
            if toks[n + 1] and toks[n + 1].cmdname == "sup_mark" and
               toks[n + 2] and toks[n + 2].cmdname == "other_char" then
                -- Convert the token right after ^ to a number by looking it up
                local rep = assert(numbers[toks[n + 2].tok], "Token is not a number")
                -- Append the stack to the result rep times
                for i = 1, rep do
                    for _, t in ipairs(stack) do
                        table.insert(result, t)
                    end
                end
                -- Flush the stack
                stack = {}
                -- Skip the next two tokens (^ and number)
                n = n + 2
            else
                -- We are not inside braces but there is also no ^, so we flush the stack
                for _, t in ipairs(stack) do
                    table.insert(result, t)
                end
                stack = {}
            end
        end

        -- Move on to the next token
        n = n + 1
    end

    -- Flush whatever is still on the stack
    for _, t in ipairs(stack) do
        table.insert(result, t)
    end

    -- Put the result back into the input stream
    token.put_next(result)
end

-- Bind the registered function to "test"
token.set_lua("test", #lft, "global")
-- The "global" definition (similar to gdef) is needed because the luacode*
-- environment is an implicit TeX group and set_lua obey TeX grouping
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
\test{$x$}

\test{$x y$}

\test{$x^1 y^12$}

\test{$x^3 y^2 z$}

\test{${x_1}^3 {a{bc}de}^2$}

\test{$\{x_1\}^3$}

\test{$\alpha^2\lambda^3\omega^4$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your example and explanations. :-) This is so powerful. I will start  seriously to use LuaTeX to do advanced formattings.