# How Can I Bundle a Figure JPG and a latex TEX file into one TEX file and have it run?

Tags: graphics, embedding

In the question at
[Can I bundle images in the source file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162013/can-i-bundle-images-in-the-source-file) there is discussion of this, the consensus being it is impossible.

What I want to do is have all files necessary to compile my tex code in one single file. My reason is that I don't want to have to
keep track of all kinds of secondary files; I want to be able to send it other people; to save visual space; to avoid having to unzip or look into a directly for files; all kinds of reasons similar to why people like to bundle an HTML file with its images into one file.

[Sorry for the length of this question, but I have less than 50 points so I can't ask it as a comment on the earlier thread. ]

One comment in the earlier thread was that it *is* possible to embed the binary JPG into the ascii TEX file, but that doesn't get you something that will run in Latex together. Someone else commented that there is some kind of shell-escape to use. Can that be embedded in the file too?

> "Technically it is possible to embed all kinds of binary data using base64 encoding. Here is a snippet by Paulo Cereda demonstrating how to do it: gist.github.com/cereda/1046388 But I believe that this is hardly a solution to the OP's problem, because the real problem appears not to be how to embed data in text files, but rather how to keep working directories in sync. –
> DG'
> Aug 19, 2014 at 13:03
> @DG' yes or uuencode (or vvencode if you remember that;-) I didn't mention that intentionally as if you want latex to unpack that you need shell-escape or a custom graphics driver setup, either of which is more bother than simply unzipping a zip file. –
> David Carlisle
> Aug 19, 2014 at 13:44"

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605391/base64-encoding-in-latex for some possible approaches to embed a base64 image

Comment: There are even dedicated packages: https://ctan.org/pkg/inline-images and https://ctan.org/pkg/luaimageembed

Comment: it's sort of possible but why not just send a zip file which is easier to make and easier to handle on whatever operating system the other people are using

Comment: Have you considered alternative approaches to share your latex document? For example via git or a collaborative editor?

Comment: oh I just noticed you had already quoted me saying more or less the same previously:-)

Comment: Sam Carter ,especially, thank you inline-images look good, maybe with this shell escape, since I've never done that before: https://ctan.org/pkg/shellesc?lang=en